# Hi, I'm working on a multi-robot project. Robots need to talk to each other directly

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm working on a multi-robot project, which robots need to talk to each other directly. Assume that robot1 wants to talk to robot3, so robot1 publishes its desire to talk. One way to solve is that robot3 subscribes to every other robots to find out which one to talk. This approach have several disadvantages like latency and confliction. I wanted to know if there is any way to solve this problem with direct connection between robots in ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187954/hi,-i%27m-working-on-a-multi-robot-project.-robots-need-to-talk-to-each-other-directly./) by [Armin](https://answers.ros.org/users/19859/armin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-07-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could imagine using services, Whenever a robot 1 wants to talk to robot 3, it calls the service of robot 3 to engage a conversation. No need for subscriptions here, every robot just need to know the name of the services for each other robot. And only then when the conversation is engaged, both robots can subscribe to each other. When the conversation ends, the subscriptions should be canceled.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Armin](https://answers.ros.org/users/19859/armin/) on 2014-07-28**:
Thanks that was really helpful.

**Comment by [Armin](https://answers.ros.org/users/19859/armin/) on 2014-08-02**:
I want to run these services on each robot but I can only init_node once in each rospy. What would you suggest?
Thanks for your help